# C# Find text in Datatable using Linq, Dot net Version 3.x

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am using WindowsFormsApplication with Dot Net version 3.5.

I am looking for a fast way to find a string in Datatable's rows. I have a string `str1` I want to search if datatable `dt` contains the text in `str1`.

I have a data table, dt like this. This is just a sample I have almost 500 strings in datatable.

```
string str1 = "Carrot";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Text");

dt.Rows.Add("Cat");

dt.Rows.Add("Dog");

dt.Rows.Add("Parrot");

dt.Rows.Add("Carrot");

dt.Rows.Add("Tomato");

dt.Rows.Add("Rabbit");

dt.Rows.Add("Pigon");
```

I am looking for some thing like this;

```
if dt.Column("Text") contains str1 then 
MessageBox.Show("The data table contains the string in str1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.Field<string>("Text") == str1))
{
    ...
}
```

If you cannot use `LINQ` then use a loop:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     if (row["Text"] == str1)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("The data table contains the string in str1");
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use 'AsEnumerable' because I am using Dot net version 3.5.

Comment: @Kami That *doesn't* prevent you from using `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Servy Yes you are right, I just searched and found that I have not added the library "System.Data.DataSetExtensions". I added it and now its working perfectly. Thanks!